# Error: 'Can't find variable' happening only in safari browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, safari, angular6

So basically i have a player and a button, when i click the button it plays the file its working for all browser except safari. Safari gives below error:

In my typescript file i have declared the variable globally as below

> declare var myPlayer: any;

The ERROR I get in SAFARI browser. I don't know what i am doing wrong.

```
Error
    line: 4999
    message: "Can't find variable: myPlayer"
    sourceId: 5067445680
    sourceURL: "http://0.0.0.0:4200/main.js"
    __proto__: Error
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with TypeScript's `declare var`, which is only used during compilation. Without seeing the context of the line it is impossible to say why you're getting the error.

Comment: Are you using some player library? Maybe the player is failing to initialize on Safari browser. What player are you using?

Comment: so i am not using any third-party player. but its a player which is built in JS

Comment: I have file my-player.js which has all the function or operation to perform, i am trying to access it in my other typescript component

Comment: So sounds like myPlayer is not included...

Comment: yes so declare var myPlayer: any; this is loading all its functions from my-player.js but not working in safari only

Comment: i have already provided the scripts path in angular.json

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I am experiencing the same error.